# Tumblr JS won't start from anywhere but 0

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I have `<script src="http://my.tumblr.com/js?start=0&num=5"></script>` which embeds 1st 5 posts, but changing start= does nothing. Trying /api/read/json does nothing either, no embed at all.

My question is, how do I effectively implement an offset?

Comment: **so what is your question?**

Comment: seems clear enough how do you understand it